# Custom SimpleMembershipProvider not initialized correctly

Tags: configuration, initialization, asp.net-membership, simplemembership

I have a custom `SimpleMembershipProvider` that is implemented in an application service layer. The provider has some of its own properties as well as those inherited from base classes. Although the overridden `Initialize` method is called on the provider, and it executes without any exceptions, inherited properties get incorrect default values such as zero or `Int32.MaxValue`. I need them to be initialized to the values provided in the configuration. How can I achieve this?

The configuration looks like this:

```
<membership defaultProvider="AbcMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AbcMembershipProvider"
         type="Abc.Services.AbcMembershipServices, Abc.Services"
         connectionStringName="Membership"
         applicationName="ABC"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         enablePasswordReset="true"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         requiresUniqueEmail="true"
         passwordFormat="Hashed"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3"
         passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         passwordValidityPeriod="30" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

The provider overrides the `Initialize` method like this:

```
public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
{
    if (config.ContainsKey("passwordValidityPeriod"))
    {
        int.TryParse(config["passwordValidityPeriod"], out _passwordValidityPeriod);
        config.Remove("passwordValidityPeriod");
    }
    base.Initialize(name, config);
}
```

During service startup, the `SimpleMembershipProvider` is initialised as follows:

```
if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("Membership", "SystemUser", "UserId", "UserName", false);
```

The `Initialize` method is called by the Membership system during the `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code, the reason this occurs is because various `MembershipProvider` properties are given a default value by `SimpleMembershipProvider` when the Provider has been initialized. For example:

```
// Inherited from MembershipProvider ==> Forwarded to previous provider if this provider hasn't been initialized
public override int MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts
{
    get { return InitializeCalled ? Int32.MaxValue : PreviousProvider.MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts; }
}
```

The way round it is to override these properties in the custom provider.